# Safari iOS: drag on element with click handler sometimes triggers click outside of element

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css, reactjs

I'm having an issue on ios/safari where clicks sometimes are incorrectly triggered.

This link renders a button in both react and regular html:
https://jsbin.com/bavesepido/edit?html,css,js,output

The following CSS rules along with a html-button is all you need:

CSS

```
  * {
    outline: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
  }
```

HTML

```
<button onclick="alert('click')">click me</button>
```

On your iOS device, you can reproduce it as follows:

1. Press the button with your finger, but don't release
2. Move your finger slowly outside of the bounds of the button
3. Release the finger.

More often than not, you'll get an alert saying a click has occurred.

Does anyone know how I can prevent this from happening? This is causing me a lot of issues.

You can see me doing it in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FlV0LaREYn8&feature=youtu.be

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `touch-action="none"` to the element with the onClick.